# What is this polynomial series?

Tags: sequences-and-series, polynomials

I've come across this simple, yet peculiar series of polynomials wich I can't quite find a general formula for.

It goes as such:

$$1$$
$$x+1$$
$$x^2+x+2$$
$$x^3+x^2+2x+6$$
$$x^4+x^3+2x^2+6x+24$$
$$\vdots$$

I'm finding these polynomials by looking at a term in the $n^{th}$ integral of Ei(x).

For example, the 5th integral of Ei(x) is;

$$\frac{1}{120}(x^5Ei(x)-e^x(x^4+x^3+2x^2+6x+24))$$

Comment: What is the rule used to generate these?

Comment: @vadim123 I'm not sure, they apear when continueing to integrate $Ei(x)$ repetitively according to Wolfram Alpha

Comment: Can you add more terms?

Comment: I have to say, it's still really difficult to see a pattern. I did notice that the coefficient of $x$, so far, is always a factorial, but I have not seen nearly enough terms to be sure.

Comment: Please add the calculation you performed to generate these polynomials.

Comment: @DonaldSplutterwit Of course, I've edited as such.

Comment: Shouldn't that be $x^4 + x^3 + 2 x^2 + 6 x + 24$?

Comment: ... and $x^3 + x^2 + 2 x + 6$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Yes! You're right.

Comment: Maybe you can get somewhere if you start from the formula for the exponential integral at http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ExponentialIntegral.html which is $$-\int_{-x}^{\infty}t^{-1}e^{-t}\,dt$$ Anyway, it looks like the coefficients are just the factorials.

Comment: Maybe it’s $\sum_{k=0}^n k!x^{n-k}$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $F_0(x) = \text{Ei}(x)$.
It seems $F_n(x) = \text{Ei}(x) \frac{x^n}{n!} - \frac{e^x}{n!} P_n(x)$ where $P_n$ is a polynomial of degree $n-1$ for $n \ge 1$ and $F_n'(x) = F_{n-1}(x)$,
which translates to 
$$ P_n'(x) + P_n(x) = P_{n-1}(x) + x^{n-1}$$ 
I get
$$
\eqalign{P_1(x) &= 1\cr
P_2(x) &= x+1\cr
P_3(x) &= {x}^{2}+x+2\cr
P_4(x) &= {x}^{3}+{x}^{2}+2\,x+6\cr
P_5(x) &= {x}^{4}+{x}^{3}+2\,{x}^{2}+6\,x+24\cr
P_6(x) &= {x}^{5}+{x}^{4}+2\,{x}^{3}+6\,{x}^{2}+24\,x+120\cr
P_7(x) &= {x}^{6}+{x}^{5}+2\,{x}^{4}+6\,{x}^{3}+24\,{x}^{2}+120\,x+720\cr}$$

It seems $$P_n(x) = \sum_{m=0}^{n-1} (n-1-m)! x^m$$
which should be easy to prove by induction.

Comment: Ah that makes a lot of sense, not sure how I could have missed that earlier.

Answer (score 3):

From the given polynomials, my guess is,

$$p_n(x)=\sum_{i=0}^n (n-i)!\cdot x^i$$

with the list starting from $n=0$

Answer (score 1):

Now that the question has been edited, my old answer does not hold, but this new sequence has an easier pattern:

Every diagonal is:

1, mult by 1 , mult by 2, mult by 3, mult by 4,...

so, $1$, $1 \times 1 = 1$, $1 \times 2 = 2$, $2 \times 3 = 6$, $6 \times 4 = 24$ ...

So it is just $(n-1)!$ as the nth diagonal entry on any given diagonal.

Answer (score 1):

Those are factorials : $1=0!,1=1!,2=2!,6=3!,24=4!,...$

Answer (score 0):

*Old answer before question was edited*:

*The difference in the earlier question was that the last coefficient of the last polynomial was $4$ and not $24$ and the last coefficient of the second-to-last polynomial was 2 and not 6*.

This is not a complete answer but an interesting pattern: One interesting observation is that any given coefficient in a row is the sum of all coefficients of a previous row whose row number is also smaller than or equal to the smallest prime divisor of the row number. (The converse also holds - the sum of coefficients in a smaller row whose row number is less than or equal to the smallest prime dividing a row will appear as a coefficient)

For example, in row $2$, all coefficients are $1$ since the only coefficient in row $1$ was $1$. In row $3$, we have a coefficient $2$ since the sum of coefficients in row $2$ was $2$, and we have a coefficient $1$ since the sum of coefficients in row $1$ was $1$. In row $4$, the smallest prime divisor is $2$, and so we are allowed only coefficients $1$ and $2$. In row $5$, we have coefficients $6$ (from row 4), $4$ (from row 3), $2$ (from row 2), and $1$ (from row 1).

---

A bit of fun: This question and my answer reminded me a bit of this comic: http://spikedmath.com/comics/062-the-iq-test.png :)

Comment: I might be misunderstanding but are you saying row 4 should have a coefficient of 4 somewhere since the coefficients of the previous poly was 1,1 , and 2; that sum being 4.  I think I might be misreading. Sorry if I am.

Comment: @randomgirl, 4 = 2^2, so the smallest prime dividing 4 is 2, so the coefficients of row 4 will either be the sum of coefficients in row 1 or the sum of coefficients in row 2. So it can have only coefficients $1$ and $2$.

Comment: Haha, love the comic. Sorry, in retrospect I messed up a few of the coefficients of the polynomials so your answer might not be as valid. (They've been corrected now)